# importmap with json in single-spa microfront

Tags: javascript, json, micro-frontend, single-spa

I am having an error when doing the dynamic import of my microfront in the root app of my application. I do it with importmap and an external json

```
<% if (isLocal) { %>
    <script type="systemjs-importmap" src="./rutas.json"> </script>
  <% } %>
```

rutas.json

```
{
  "imports": {
    "@single-spa/welcome": "https://unpkg.com/single-spa-welcome/dist/single-spa-welcome.js",
    "@root-spa/root-config": "//localhost:9000/root-spa-root-config.js",
    "@spa-nav/spa-nav": "http://localhost:8080/spa-nav-spa-nav.js",
    "@spa-films/spa-films": "http://localhost:9001/main.js"
  }
}
```

Error in console
"Error: Error fetching systemjs-import map  (SystemJS Error#W4 )
Invalid status code: 404"

Unhandled Promise rejection: Unable to resolve bare specifier '@root-spa/root-config' from http://localhost:9000/ (SystemJS Error#8 ) ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Unable to resolve bare specifier '@root-spa/root-config' from http://localhost:9000/ (SystemJS Error#8

apart I added this in my webpackconfig.js

```
   devServer: {
          static:'src'
        }
```